# Why is my smaller method giving me an error

Tags: java, return, this, geometry

This is my first class called class circle:

```
public class circle
{
   //circle class begins
   //declaring variables 
   public double circle1;
   public double circle2;
   public double circle3;
   public double Xvalue;
   public double Yvalue;
   public double radius;
   private double area;

   //Constructor
   public circle(int x,int y,int r)
   {//constructor begins
       Xvalue = x;
       Yvalue = y;
       radius = r;
   }//constructor ends

   //method that gets the area of a circle       
   public double getArea ()
   {//method getArea begins

      area = (3.14*(this.radius * this.radius));
      return area;
   }//getArea ends

   public static smaller (circle other)
   {
      if (this.area > other.area)
      {
         return other;
      else 
      {
         return this;
      }

      //I'm not sure what to return here. it gives me an error( I want to return a circle)
    }
}//class ends
}
```

This is my tester class:

```
public class tester
{//tester begins
  public static void main(String args [])
  {

        circle circle1 = new circle(4,9,4);
        circle circle2 = new circle(4,7,6);
        c3 = c1.area(c2);

        System.out.println(circle1.getArea());
        //System.out.println(
  }
}//class tester ends
```

Comment: "_it gives me an error_"; what is that error?

Comment: `c3` doesn't have a type.

Answer (score 2):

The `smaller` method should have a return type. Also the `this` keyword cannot be used in a `static` method. i.e. the method will not have access to the instance of `Circle`. This make sense given what the method name `smaller` implies - it compares the current instance of `Circle` with another passed in.

```
public Circle smaller(circle other) {
   if (this.area > other.area) {
    return other;
   } else {
    return this;
   }
}
```

To use:

```
Circle smallerCircle = circle1.smaller(circle2);
```

`Aside:` Java naming conventions show that class names start with an *uppercase* letter to give `Circle`.

Comment: If he copy pasted though, the method will throw an error since his class is declared as "circle" currently and not "Circle". Your return type is not the same as your parameter.

Comment: Yes but I did explain that at the end and want to encourage the use of the Java naming conventions :)

Comment: Lol no I get it and understand. I just hope he doesn't open another question worrying about why he's getting errors. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Area is unassigned when you make the operation :

```
 c3 = c1.area(c2);
```

You need to make the GeArea() call before you can use the area field of the class.

So for example:

```
circle circle1 = new circle(4,9,6);

circle circle2 = new circle(4,7,6);
circle2.area = c1.getArea();
```

That is assuming that the c3 var you're trying to assign to has been instantiated as a circle.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot a closing brace

```
if (this.area > other.area)
{
    return other;
} //You forgot this brace and confused the compiler
else 
{
    return this;
}
```